# Why user private function?

Tags: javascript, private-methods

So the have seem something like this today:

```
$$('input').each(function() {
 // do something
});
```

What is the difference between that and this:

```
$$('input').each( // do something );
```

The private function on the first example is within that for loop scope, so it is not reference-able anywhere else, so what would the benefit of having it?

Comment: ... not using a function literal would throw a syntax error, because arbitrary JavaScript can't be embedded in parentheses?

Comment: You _could_ define an external function and pass it in to each like so: `function foo() { alert('foo!') }; $('.input').each(foo);` OR you could make an anonymous function and pass it in like you did in your first example: `$('.input').each( function() { alert('foo!') } );`

Comment: @minitech, so what you are saying is I can have something like this? $(something).each( a=b; c=d; e=f);

Comment: @Churk: No, you can't have that. That's what closures (anonymous functions) are for.

Comment: @minitech Ok, that make sense now. The point of having that anonymous functions and the added benefit of scoping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anonymous function knows its current scope and variables.

```
function a() {
   var foo = 'test';
   $('something').each(function() {
      alert(foo);
   })
}
```

This function would alert 'test' because `foo` is defined within its scope.

```
function a() {
   var foo = 'test';
   $('something').each(b)
}

function b() {
   alert(foo);
}
```

This function would cause a javascript error stating that the variable `foo` is undefined.

If you need to define a function that only makes sense within an exact scope and don't want to throw lots of variables around or recalculate a lot of things, it's more comfortable to define an anonymous function.

Answer (score 2):

This is not private function, it's just an anonymous function (function without name).

You could do:

```
$('input').each(function() {
 // do something
});
```

Or you could do:

```
function foo() {
 // do something
}
$('input').each(foo);
```

Anyway, the `.each` method needs a function to be the parameter which is a callback.

Comment: the .each is just something I picked out as an example, but you are right, the .each() is a callback, but I have seem this on non-callback iterating function.

Answer (score 1):

The first function is not private. It can reference all variables in the containing scope to form a closure, because JavaScript has lexical scoping.

The second function is pretty much the same thing, except the only thing you can do is provide it with a function name, or you will get a syntax error.

Short Answer: You put the function statement there to do more than one thing, or do one thing and provide parameters.

Comment: So the function allows you to pass in more parameter, such as $(a).each(function(c){ // do something with c}); where as I couldn't the other way. Ahhhh, thanks